# How does one get standard ps modules to import in C# core 2.2?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to create a scheduled task via the powershell sdk in a core 2.2 but when I invoke I get a bunch of exceptions on the pipeline for cmdlets not found:

`The term 'Register-ScheduledTask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

I used the code from the following blog post from Keith Babinec: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

This runs other powershell scripts (that don't have "fancy" modules) just fine.

Here is the Code:

```
        public async Task<int> ExecuteAsynchronously(string script)
        {
            //This finds the modules but I cannot use them, even when I try to import them with the "Import-Module" command
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
           iss.ImportPSModulesFromPath(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" );

            Console.WriteLine("ExecutingPowerShell: " + script);
            try
            {
                using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
                {
                    runspace.Open();

                    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                       PowerShellInstance.Runspace = runspace;

                        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();


                        var command =  File.ReadAllText(script);

                        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(command);


                        PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
                        outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;

                        PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;

                        try
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("running task");
                            IAsyncResult result = await Task.Run(() => PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection));
                            Console.WriteLine("finished running task");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Execution has stopped. The pipeline state: " + PowerShellInstance.InvocationStateInfo.State);

                        foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Here is the ps script:

```
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Hidden -Compatibility Win8
$Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = 'PT0S' 
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -RunLevel Highest
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Launch Webserver' -InputObject $Task
```

Here are the relevant installed packages:

```
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure        {1.0.0}    
Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK                   {6.2.3}    
System.Management.Automation               {6.2.3}
```

This is running on win10 (I had to add/hack the win10 x64 target in .pubxml). It is being coded in VS2019.

I have a way of creating the scheduled tasks in c# but I want this method to be able to run anything that uses the modules in:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Thanks for any help! I am flummoxed!

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with Powershell script modules as well.

I created a simple module which return a string, so nothing fancy. But no matter what i try i can't get it to import.

I tried InitialSessionState.ImportPSModulesFromPath("path") but it doesn't get imported it seems and then just throws an error on my command, that it doesn't exist.

If i create a ps1 script and calls that, which then imports the module and runs the command, then it works..
But then i will have to create "run" scripts for all my custom functions, and write double code all over the place.